# What happens if you attack a chosen stronghold before saving a captured soldier?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

So, I'm at the point where I could attack the stronghold of the chosen assassin, who captured

> Pratal Mox

in one of the early story missions. I actually kinda forgot about that, so that person is still locked away and waiting to be saved.

However, assuming that you are guaranteed to run into the chosen assassin in that rescue mission, I wondered what would happen if you defeated a chosen permanently before saving a soldier captured by them.

- Do they get "saved" automatically at the end of the chosen stronghold mission?
- Is the mission still playable, without any interference from the chosen?
- Does the mission glitch out in some way (captured soldier vanishes forever, chosen shows up despite being dead, etc)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Despite what you might think, captive soldiers aren't actually held in the Chosen's personal stronghold -- they use Advent facilities for that. (Nor are you guaranteed to run into the chosen on rescue missions targeting that soldier).

The mission should still be accessible via covert ops (and may even be safer, since you've already dealt with the Chosen), but they won't get automatically saved once their kidnapper breathes their last.